# Link for download latest Edubuntu

Tags: edubuntu

I want to download latest Edubuntu version from the official Edubuntu website, but its links fail. Can you fix it?

Sorry for my English and best regards,
Stano.

Comment: [https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-14-04-end-of-life/](https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-14-04-end-of-life/)

Comment: As of 23.04 the link is fixed and working now: https://www.edubuntu.org/

Answer (score 7):

Edubuntu is discontinued. The latest release was 14.04.

Comment: And 14.04 is past End of Life, so therefore Edubuntu is as well.

Comment: @K7AAY I think the "(14.04)" on [that page](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) is intended to mean that Edubuntu became an official derivative starting with the 14.04 release, and thus that questions about it were on-topic starting with that release. Newly asked questions asking for help doing something on Edubuntu 14.04 (besides upgrading it) are probably off-topic under our policy about "end of life" releases. But installing and using the software provided by tasks or metapackages like `edubuntu-desktop` in supported Ubuntu releases is almost certainly on-topic.

Comment: Tossed that into meta https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18764/edubuntu-14-04-supported-by-askubuntu-com for deeper minds than mine to ponder.

Comment: This answer seems to be superseded: Edubuntu has been resurrected in 23.04 and is a real flavor or Ubuntu again. Web site: https://www.edubuntu.org/ , Release Notes: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/edubuntu-23-04-released/35281

Answer (score 2):

In very exciting development (pun intended) Edubuntu has roared back to life in 2023 and returned to download servers with Edubuntu 23.04, codenamed "Lunar Lobster".

From [the announcement](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/edubuntu-23-04-released/35281):

> We are pleased to announce the release of Edubuntu 23.04, codenamed “Lunar Lobster”. This has been a project of love for my husband Erich and myself and I am happy to see it back with the people where it belongs once again.
>
> This release will be supported for nine months (Until January 2025).

Thus the *direct* link to the latest Edubuntu download (as requested by the OP) is here:

- [Edubuntu 23.04 Lunar Lobster](https://cdimages.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/23.04/release/edubuntu-23.04-desktop-amd64.iso): Desktop image for 64-bit PC (AMD64) computers (standard download)

While a link to the actual download page [is here](https://cdimages.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/23.04/release/). Exciting times :)